# PHP SOAP generating correct schema

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Hi im having some trouble creating a schmea using PHP.

I need to generate something similar to :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="http://some-url">
    <soapenv:Header> 
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://some-url">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-837" xmlns:wsu="http://some-url">
                <wsse:Username>account-username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://some-url">account-password</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce>NuehdiIAyh==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2009-05-07T21:41:49.765Z</wsu:Created> 
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security> 
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body> 
        <loc:getLocation>
            <loc:address>some-address</loc:address> 
            <loc:maximumAge> 
                <metric>Second</metric> 
                <units>100</units>
            </loc:maximumAge>
            <loc:responseTime> 
                <metric>Second</metric> 
                <units>100</units>
            </loc:responseTime>
            <loc:tolerance>LowDelay</loc:tolerance> 
        </loc:getLocation>
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've had 0 luck though. I tried some examples using Soapvar,Soapparam, anyone have an idea how I can go by doing this?

Comment: A little more info on what you are doing?  It would help a great deal.

Comment: trying to connect to a soap server wsdl and execute the top request to get a response.

Answer (score 1):

NuSOAP is an excellent toolkit for SOAP. It's quite easy to use, and the support is very good.

http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=552239

There is an excellent documentation available on how to create SOAP Scheme's.